# WP 4.4 aspect ratio with responsive image

Tags: images, responsive

How to make new WP responsive image to choose images by filename and add them to srcset without checking aspect ratio?

I have my own sizes:

```
add_image_size( 'l', 992, 500, array( 'center', 'center' ) );
add_image_size( 'm', 768, 500, array( 'center', 'center' ) );
add_image_size( 'sm', 450, 300, array( 'center', 'center' ) );
```

And I want to use them in srcset.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't.

srcset is used for when you want to optimise the quality for different devices by serving different sizes of the **same** image. If you want to serve different crops, you should be using the **picture** element instead.

For example, if the intention of your image sizes is to serve a 'small' version to 'mobile' devices, using srcset won't achieve that. For example, an iPhone 6, despite only being 414px wide, would serve your large 992x500 image due to being 3x retina quality.

Comment: Good point. I'm not using Apple products and I'm always forgeting about them. But I think that picture element isn't solution for retina display (http://caniuse.com/#search=picture). 

I need different crop for different devices. Object-fit for img isn't working for any MS browsers same as object-fit polyfill. 

I don't want to use images as background-size: cover, because site would have many big size images and making queries and manually adding them would be a nightmare. 

Any suggestions how can I achieve it?

Comment: scrset is for serving the same image in different sizes. The picture element is for art direction. Everything else is a hacky workaround and wrong.